# how to make half circle at the background for a div in ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Does anyone know how to make half circle for a div background in ionic as shown in the picture?

[image]

I tried to create one with the below code but it doesn`t for my case.

```
<div class="half-circle"></div>

.half-circle {
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: gold;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
 border-top-right-radius: 100px;
 border: 10px solid gray;
 border-left: 0;

 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

CSS help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple background with [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) where you can easily control the shape and its position:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:25px;
  background:radial-gradient(50% 20px at top,blue 95%,transparent 100%);
}
.box-alt {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:25px;
  background:radial-gradient(40% 22px at top,blue 95%,transparent 100%);
}

.box-alt-2 {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:25px;
  background:radial-gradient(40% 22px at 50% -5px,blue 95%,transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text here
</div>

<div class="box-alt">
  some text here
</div>

<div class="box-alt-2">
  some text here
</div>
```

The syntax is `radial-gradient([horizontal radius] [vertical radius] at [position of the center point], [coloration])`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
}
.half-circle {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
}
.name {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="half-circle"></div>
  <div class="name">My name is</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you are very close. But it has 25% of the circle at the top of the div. My text might be in multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

You can create this shape using the pseudo element `::before` and a background `linear-gradient`.

It works like this (I added a border for clarification:

[image]

This way, you can create a very flat half circle and you can position it as you like. Also multiple text lines are no problem at all, since the circle is always at the top of the div. Here is a working example:

```css
.half-circle {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.half-circle::before {
  content: "";
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, transparent 50%, #0072f7 50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle">
  My name is<br />
  somebody
</div>
```

Another approach would be, to fill the pseudo element completely and hide the upper half with `overflow: hidden`:

```css
.half-circle {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.half-circle::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #0072f7;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle">
  My name is<br />
  somebody
</div>
```

Of course you should use proper vendor prefixes for browser compatibility.

Comment: you can color the full pseudo element an rely on overflow:hidden to hide the top part of it